# Is my iPad Air 4 battery problem hardware or software related?

Tags: ipad, battery, charging

I got a used iPad Air 4 off from eBay, for an arguably great price, but without warranty: shame on me!

In principle it works great, but there is a thing concerning the battery lifetime that puzzles me: from the Apple Analytics logfile I read

last_value_MaximumCapacityPercentage=97

Which seems to indicate a battery health of 97%. Also a third party Windows Tool claims that I have a healthy battery. Therefore the seller was right do describe the battery condition as ‚good‘.

But then, when I first unpacked and used the iPad, I experienced massive battery drain even with lightest task, which was capped when I went to bed with the iPad in standby at like 2/3 charge only to wake up to a dead iPad with a new LowBatteryLog-file. I seem to get like 40 minutes of screen time and 10 h of standby time out of the device.

[image]

I repeated the process and left it with 100% charge at 11 pm, and now see the charge Evolution with like 30 minutes of screen time, and the main drain app is the Home Screen. especially over the course of the remainding night, the battery already lost 40 % of its charge

This contradicts my expectations from the battery condition alone, and I’ve often read about software related issues which lead to exhaustive battery draining. May this be the case with my device?
Does an obvious culprit come to mind from my mere description?

Or is the battery nuts and I should try for a refund / repair it / resell it?

Good god, how I wished to have paid 50 bucks more not to have this issue  be wise and learn from my stupid bean counter mistake

Answer (score 3):

#### Your battery isn’t holding a charge.

There’s no software that can “spot measure” this because it it’s something that must be measured over time.  This way, the amount of *current* can be calculated  and that value compared to what is remaining in the battery.

You’ve already ruled out software - the home screen doesn’t do much (in terms of processing) and if that is the process draining your battery, it definitely hardware related.

> …a third party Windows Tool claims that I have a healthy battery. Therefore the seller was right do describe the battery condition as ‚good‘.

This is not correct.  The only thing you confirmed here was that the battery charged to 97% of its capacity, not that it was “good.”

To determine if a battery is good, it must be tested under a known load and since the battery is not easily disconnected, this means unless the app cycles up the CPU and measures the current drain, you’re just getting a spot check at that moment in time.

This is why you need to look for the phrase it “it holds a charge for X hours” or at the very minimum ask.

You need to return it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that your first action is to try to return it to the seller and get a refund.

If that's not possible, then you can get a new battery from Apple for $119.

(On some of the iPad models, Apple actually just gives you a new device, rather than 'repairing' it.)

A new battery from Apple will of course comes with a full warranty.